# Can we do parallel execution using Cucumber Gradle

Tags: gradle, cucumber, bdd

Hi i have gone through various articles online but couldn't find any good resource with proper documentation  that talks about gradle supporting parallel execution with cucumber. Any proper documentation or and example will help me in adding parallel execution to my existing automation test. My task is simple running different feature files in parallel.

Comment: Well could you share your current setup. How do you run cucumber with gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute Cucumber in parallel with JUnit 5. Taking the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) as an example.

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.8.1"))

    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    // Work around. Gradle does not include enough information to disambiguate
    // between different examples and scenarios.
    systemProperty("cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy", "long")
}
```

This uses the JUnit Platform Suite Engine to run Cucumber:

```java
package io.cucumber.skeleton;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "io.cucumber.skeleton")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

And finally to enable parallel execution we can find in the [cucumber-junit-platform-engine documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine) that parallel execution can be enabled by adding to `junit-platform.properties`:

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Cucumber runner for Gradle a couple of years ago. The purpose was to run things in parallel. I still use it and sometimes I even get pull requests for improvements.

You might find it useful.

https://github.com/tsundberg/gradle-cucumber-runner

Answer (score -1):

If you use a single suite engine class to load all your cucumber files, then this is your problem. All that Gradle sees, is that single class. Gradle can only deal with test classes, that is why the suite engine workaround is even needed.

If you want to be able to use multiple forks, then you need to create more suite classes, if you want to go for maximum parallelism you'd need a 1-to-1 mapping.

You could try to create those suite classes automatically in a custom task that runs before the `test` task.